# ArrayList add() function is duplicating my data

Tags: java, arraylist

The title may be a bit confusing, so I will demonstrate what is happening through code. I have used ArrayLists in the past, so I am either missing something really obvious, or I assume it's something to do with my Java version (jdk1.7.0_75/jre1.7.0).

```
    public void test()
    {
    List<Objects> horse = new ArrayList<Objects>(); 
    Objects OBJECT = new Objects(63, 63, 63, 0, 1, 10, 0);
    Objects OBJECT2 = new Objects(64, 64, 64, 0, 2, 10, 0);
    Objects OBJECT3 = new Objects(77, 77, 77, 0, 1, 10, 0);
    horse.add(OBJECT);
    horse.add(OBJECT2);
    horse.add(OBJECT3);
    for (Objects o : horse)
    {
        System.out.println(o.objectX);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
77
77
77
```

The Objects class:

```
package server.model.objects;


public class Objects {

    public long delay, oDelay;
    public int xp, item, owner, target, times;
    public boolean bait;

    public static int objectId;
    public static int objectX;
    public static int objectY;
    public int objectHeight;
    public int objectFace;
    public int objectType;
    public int objectTicks;

    public static int getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public static int getObjectX() {
        return objectX;
    }

    public static int getObjectY() {
        return objectY;
    }


    public Objects(int id, int x, int y, int height, int face, int type, int ticks) {
        Objects.objectId = id;
        Objects.objectX = x;
        Objects.objectY = y;
        this.objectHeight = height;
        this.objectFace = face;
        this.objectType = type;
        this.objectTicks = ticks;
    }




    public int getObjectHeight() {
        return this.objectHeight;
    }

    public int getObjectFace() {
        return this.objectFace;
    }

    public int getObjectType() {
        return this.objectType;
    }
}
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to show us your `Objects` class. My guess is that `objectX` is a static variable. (You should also follow Java naming conventions, and think of better names for your classes than `Objects`.)

Comment: *"ArrayList add() function is duplicating my data"* No, it isn't. Something *else* is going on.

Comment: You're right Jon. Thank you very much. I'm working on an open source project to improve my skills.

Thank you T.J and Jon.

Comment: Jon Skeet's psychic debugging skills once again prove useful.

Comment: How can I upvote in this comments section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objectX` is a static variable in your code, meaning that whenever it's tied to the `Objects` class as a whole, not to any particular instance, and changing it one place changes it *everywhere.*

Making it not a static variable should fix things.